# Hide unused levels in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Recently I was forced to update R to version 4.05, and since then I have an unexpected behaviour in ggplot. I want ggplot to hide unused factor levels in the legend. This should work with the following code. And it did work in my older R version.

Does anyone know, what I have to change in R 4.05? In this example I expect only to see "VC" (red) in the legend.

```
library(tidyverse)

mycols <- setNames(c('red' , 'blue') ,
                   c('VC' , 'OJ'))

ToothGrowth %>% filter(supp == 'VC') %>%
ggplot(aes(x=len , y = supp)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = supp)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycols , drop = TRUE)
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4511#issuecomment-866185530

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK; the related issue 4511 gives the answer. Setting `limits = force` in scale_fill_manual did it.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if this solved the issue.

Comment: I wanted to accept my own answer. But it's only allowed in two days it says.